# i am trying to use MAX_FILE_SIZE to get a instant file check before user uploads a file

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

Yes i am aware that this is not something to relay on since it can easily be changed and hacked.

My question is does MAX_FILE_SIZE return a instant response or does it also have to wait to upload.

And if any one can provide a clear code on how to get it working.. much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#74692

Comment: im trying to prevent user from uploading a file bigger then allowed.  user, not hacker.  I know its not a fool proof plan.  in the worst case i have LimitRequestBody set on apache to prevent those. Thanks.

Comment: No PHP is run before the file is either uploaded, or fails because it's too big.

Comment: what does php have to do with this?

Comment: @john: You used the *php* tag. That's "what".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is running on server. Therefore you must have the checking placed on browser (client side) using a client side scripting language such as javascript.